# Plain JS: make 80% width element 100% IF contains an image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, width

In my wordpress posts I want the text paragraphs to be 80% width but the images to be 100% width of the content area. However the images are wrapped in `<p>` tags so I want to write a little script that finds all the p tags in a post, and if any contains an img element - give the p tag a class that is specified 100% width in the CSS.

I found a way to do it with getElementByID:

```
    var kids = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('p');

    var looper = function(t){
    for(i=0; i<kids.length; i++){
      if(t[i].firstChild.tagName === "IMG"){
        t[i].setAttribute("class", "postimg");
      }
    }
    };

looper(kids);
```

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/meculi/

I am not sure how best to proceed when the content area has a class but no id the `getElementsByTagName` cannot be a method of `getElementsByClassName.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like list of elements, so you can't call element methods on its results. You can loop through the results and run your loop for each one, but I'd suggest a simpler solution: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var kids = document.querySelectorAll('.content p');
```

That would make `kids` a NodeList that your loop code should work with. You could even take it a step further and let `querySelectorAll` do the work of finding the paragraphs containing images:

```
var paragraph_images = document.querySelectorAll('.content p > img');

for (var i = 0; i < paragraph_images.length; i++) {
    paragraph_images[i].parentNode.className += ' postimg';
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much for this simple solution. I didn't use querySelectorAll because i've been told it's not as cross-browser as other methods.

Comment: @Rup Unless you're targeting IE 7 and below, browser support isn't an issue. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector